# Android - Warning after update google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

After update my google play service version to last released version, when enable minify in debug or release the following warning shown and task not complete. 
`Warning:io.nlopez.smartlocation.activity.ActivityStore: can't find referenced method 'DetectedActivity(int,int,int)' in program class com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity`

Updated version : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'`

I add this line in my gradle `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue i use this [Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) in my project and Google play services version 10.2.0 is incompatible with this library

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Google Play Service location package:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
```

Also you should check SmartLocation library description, last compatible version of Google Play Services 10.0.1:

> https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib
>
> ...
> Google Play Services compatible version: 10.0.1

So, I think, you should downgrade Grade Google Play service to v. 10.0.1, is you use SmartLocation library

Comment: Thanks for your time